# Objective C Macro Library that Uses '$'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macros

Recently, I came across a useful Objective C macro library on Github. The library cleverly used the '$' to denote its macros. For example, $dict(key1, obj1, key2, obj2) would return a NSDictionary with its respective keys and values.

Do you know the name of this library and its Github url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it: ConciseKit [[https://github.com/petejkim/ConciseKit]](https://github.com/petejkim/ConciseKit)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which specific library you are discussing, but mine has some similar macros and I invite you to add more along these lines:

```
#define $array(objs...) [NSArray arrayWithObjects: objs, nil] 
#define $set(objs...) [NSSet setWithObjects: objs, nil] 
#define $format(format, objs...) [NSString stringWithFormat: format, objs]
```

It also defines $rect, $point, $size, etc.

https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils/blob/master/es_ios_utils

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Jens Ayton's JANumberLiteral](http://jens.ayton.se/blag/objc-constant-objects/), which uses the same syntax, but it's specifically for NSNumbers only.